# How to annotate a field as deprecated in OpenAPI (Swagger) 2.0?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I have the following schema definition:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...
definitions:
  Service:
    type: object
    properties:
      serviceId:
        type: string
        description: Device or service identification number
        example: 1111111111      
      location:
        type: string
        description: Location of the service
        example: '400 Street name, City State postcode, Country'
```

I would like to do annotate the `location` field as deprecated. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 125):

The possibility to mark schemas and schema properties as `deprecated` was added in OpenAPI 3.0:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
...
components:
  schemas:
    Service:
      type: object
      properties:
        location:
          type: string
          description: Location of the service
          example: '400 Street name, City State postcode, Country'
          deprecated: true    # <---------
```

If you use OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0), the only thing you can do is document the deprecation verbally in the property `description`.

Answer (score 30):

According to the [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/paths-and-operations/) it is enough to use the `deprecated` attribute:

```yaml
paths:
  /pet/findByTags:
    get:
      deprecated: true
```

Comment: He asked for "ttribute", not the endpoint. @Helen has a correct anwer: not possible in OpenAPI 2.0

Comment: @Samoht while you're correct that this doesn't answer the question, Google will show this as the top result for "swagger service deprecated"